# Actual use case scenario of Drools in Talend

Tags: drools, talend, drools-guvnor

Can anyone explain me what is actual use case of Drools in Talend. I am trying to learn Drool as I use Talend for Data management. But every tutorial or instruction set I find on internet are just copy of official Drool documentation.

I want to see drool in action (say, example based on Employee master and so on). The reason is that though, I am able to create basic conditions in drools, I can't figure out how to actually implement it.

Can anybody help me with it?

Comment: There is no such thing as "actual use case of Drools in Talend". Talend is for generic data management, Drools is a generic rule based system. Have you read https://engage.redhat.com/forms/rule-design-patterns yet? Also, there are some inexpensive books available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use drools rule in Talend.

For Talend Open studio you have to write java code to integrate Drools in Talend.

If you are using enterprise version then go to the `repository>>metatadata>>rules`

there you can create rules and then it can be used in Talend Job flow.

For more information read about **tRule** component.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. The OP specifically asks for use cases for Drools in Talend rather than if it's possible.